# Search through an array of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I'm having an array of `NSManagedObjects`. And I would like to search through the whole array using search bar. But the problem is in the array of `NSManagedObject` there are different types of keys(Different entities). Like if I'm search using title than there will be keys like:

"`event_title`"

"`message_title`"

"`album_title`"

Now how can I search a keyword from all these fields inside an array?

Comment: It is unusual to have different entity types in the same array, but if you are using Core Data you wouldn't typically search the array anyway.  You would use an `NSPredicate` to fetch the matching objects from the Core Data store.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a protocol with a property for searching and then have all the NSManagedObject sub-classes implement that protocol returning whatever field to search on. This of course requires that they are all of the same type or can be cast to the same type

```
protocol SearchableKey {
   var searchKey: String
}

class Event: NSManagedObject, SearchableKey {
   var searchKey: String {
      return someFieldInEvent
   }
}
```

and then then you set your search bar to search on searchKey

*Edit: I see now that this is tagged with objective-c and my answer is using swift but hopefully it will be useful anyway*

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `Event` as yours `NSManagedObject`

```
var events = [Event]()

var event1 = Event()
event1.event_title = "Musical Bang"
event1.message_title = "Wellcome to all"
event1.album_title = "Bang bang"


var event2 = Event()
event2.event_title = "Mountain View"
event2.message_title = "Free passes available"
event2.album_title = "Hunt for freedom"


events.append(event1)
events.append(event2)


func search(for searchText: String) -> Any{
    let filtered = events.filter { (value) -> Bool in
        return value.event_title.hasPrefix(searchText) || value.message_title.hasPrefix(searchText) || value.album_title.hasPrefix(searchText)
    }
    return filtered
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Some time you will never get an exact answer, you have to think it by your self also. Anyway I have changed my answer as per the question asked

Comment: You still don't get it. The array contains objects of different types, you are assuming they are of the same type so your answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: Yeah, I understood the question but, here you and I should understand one more thing is that there are different keys to another managed object so in order to perform the specific search criteria we have to specify the exact key path inside the search function. i.e, value.event_title.{key}.{key}.hasPrefix(searchText). So the key path should me know to give the exact solution.

Comment: So you are saying that if the array contains 3 types of objects then 3 searches has to be performed with different key paths per search?

Comment: Yes, Let's assume you are having the Event as the main object and inside you have sub-object so you have to apply filter to all of them

Comment: Yeah well that is not what OP is saying in the question, it says "Different entities", so unless the question is incorrectly written there is no main object but only objects of different types in the array.

Comment: In such case we have we have a pretty good condition for object check 'isKindOfClass', so checking the object type and put the valid search key for it.